# Please allow users to see votes received as well as votes given

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, voting, profile-page, statistics

On our profile page it lists how many upvotes and downvotes we've handed out. What I'd also find interesting is to see how many votes of each type we've *received*. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3):

I don't see why this couldn't be possible. There already is a very long-way-around for this by going through your reputation list and keeping track of all the numbers there and adding them up...but also this wouldn't track things that were deleted.

Answer (score 2):

Your reputation is basically this, summarized as a single number.

I don't think we want to show upvote / downvote received count, as it will lead to heartache and more support emails than we already get.

Comment: it is EXTREMELY HIGHLY CORRELATED. As in, nearly perfect correlation.

Comment: It really isn't. The higher up you go on relative ranking, the greater the number of votes for which no rep was awarded (ie above the daily cap). Some users have won no bounties. Others a lot. Sorry, the but the idea that someone might complain cos their reputation is 10 out from 10*upvotes is, well, ridiculous.

Comment: You know it'll happen though.