# Ability to see recieved votes sorted by time

Tags: feature-request, voting, profile-page

> Related, not the same: [Please allow users to see votes received as well as votes given](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4133/please-allow-users-to-see-votes-received-as-well-as-votes-given)

I generally use the rep dropdown to keep track of how well my posts are doing. Unfortunately, this doesn't work once you've hit the repcap. Also, it's completely useless on metas.

Could we have a way to see (recent) votes sorted by time?

Yes, I can see the obvious decline reason: What use is "keeping track of your posts"? Many times I post something which I'm not sure of, and I indicate this. Looking at the votes helps me realise that what I posted is in/correct. Also, on meta posts, I can guage the community opinion via votes (pretty useful, since you then have a better idea of what the community likes/does not like). I do *not* like having to trawl through lists of my posts, checking for changes.

Comment: Yeah...it *used* to work after you hit the rep cap. They broke that. I wouldn't mind having it back, but I guess all those `0`s caused too much [butt-hurt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_aversion).

Comment: But what's wrong with [the "reputation" tab in your profile, sorted by "time"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/178438/manishearth?tab=reputation&sort=time)? Am I missing something about this feature request?

Comment: @TheE there's a bunch of rolling up and all that happens. Also, the rep tab is empty on metas. And metas are the one place where this is really useful.